# Example of rings of the same positive characteristic that do not embed into their tensor product?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples, tensor-products, positive-characteristic

I'm overcoming my fear of tensor products, and the following exercise got me wondering:

> Give an example of commutative rings $A$ and $B$ with $\operatorname{char}A=\operatorname{char}B$ such that the map
>   $$A \longrightarrow\ A\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}}B:\ a\ \longmapsto\ a\otimes1,$$
>   is *not* injective.

Examples with $\operatorname{char}A\neq\operatorname{char}B$ are of course abundant, and examples with $\operatorname{char}A=\operatorname{char}B=0$ aren't too difficult either. But I am unable to find an example with $\operatorname{char}A=\operatorname{char}B>0$. An example would be very welcome, but a clue as to where to look for one would also be much (or even more?) appreciated.

Comment: Tensor product over which ring ?

Comment: Then take $B=A/I$ and the tensor product over $A$.

Comment: Dear Servaes, the same kind of example works. Just take $A$ equal to some suiable quotient of $\mathbb Z$. Over a ring $R$, $M\otimes_R R/I=M/IM$ for any $R$-module $M$.

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: @Servaes : [... and examples with $\operatorname{char}A=\operatorname{char}B=0$ aren't too difficult either]-->could you elaborate ? I have in mind a "devil" with $\operatorname{char}(k)=0$ by Goodearl 1971 for unembedding of $k[[x]]\otimes k[[y]]$ in $k[[x,y]]$ which make me cautious (I agree this is not the same case however)

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I think this can't be done.  Assuming there's nothing wrong with the following proof:

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are rings of characteristic $m$, and that $a \otimes 1 = 0$ in $A \otimes_\mathbb{Z} B$ for some $a \in A$.

This means that we must have $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b \in B$ such that $1 = n b$ and $n a = 0$, so that $$a \otimes 1 = a \otimes (n b) = (n a) \otimes b = 0 \otimes b = 0.$$

Now we have both $m a = 0$ and $n a = 0$, so by the Euclidean algorithm we see that $$\gcd(m, n) a = 0.$$

On the other hand, we have $m b = 0$ and $n b = 1$.  Write $m = \gcd(m, n) \, m'$.  Then we have

$$m' (1) = m' (n b) = (m' n) b = 0$$

since $m = m' \gcd(m, n)$ divides $m' n$.  Since $m'(1) = 0$ in $B$, $0 < m' \leq m$, and $B$ is of characteristic $m$, this means that $m'=m$, i.e. $\gcd(m,n)=1$.  From above, this says that $1 \cdot a = 0$, i.e. $a = 0$.

Comment: @servaes: If $n\cdot 1_B$ is a unit in $B$, it doesn't seem to follow immediately that $n \cdot 1_A$ is a unit in $A$.

Comment: To make the argument above completely rigorous you have to assume that $a \otimes 1$ is an element of the kernel of the map $FA(A \times B) \to A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B$, write it as a linear combination of the generators for that kernel, and reduce to the case above.  I haven't done this yet, but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Following the idea of Goodearl, I consider 
the product 
$$
\prod_{n\geq 1}\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}
$$ 
and the ring $A$ generated by its unit and 
$$
\oplus_{n\geq 1}\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}
$$ 
with $B=\mathbb{Q}$ we have a counterexample, but 
this is for 
$\operatorname{char}A=\operatorname{char}B=0$. 
I am more and more curious to see a counterexample 
(or a general statement) for positive characteristic. 

For $\operatorname{char}A=\operatorname{char}B$ prime, 
the mapping 
$$
a\ \longmapsto\ a\otimes1
$$
is, of course, injective.